# HTML Heading Causing screen flickering

Tags: javascript, html, stm32

I am using a STM32F407 as a simple webserver that uses a small script to build some tables and there is screen flicker every time it refreshes. I removed the body tags and this got rid of the flicker. This seems like bad practice but did work. Then when I add a heading above the table it flickers again. So when I add the following line: `<h1>Mini Web Server</h1>` to the HTML below the screen will flicker, when I remove it its fine. Why is this happening?

```html
"<!DOCTYPE html>\
<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=http://192.168.0.28\">\
<HTML>\
      <HEAD>\
            <TITLE>Web Server</TITLE>\
            <h1>Mini Web Server</h1>\
            <script src=/s></script>\
                    <table><tr><td valign=top><table border=1 style=\"font-size:20px ;font-family: terminal ;\">\
                            <tr><th colspan=2>ADC</th></tr>\
                            <tr><td>AN3</td><td><script>document.write(AN3)</script></td></tr>\
                     </table>\
                            </td><td><table border=1 style=\"font-size:20px ;font-family: terminal ;\">\
                            <tr><th colspan=2>PORTD</th></tr>\
                            <script>\
                                     var str,i;str=\"\";for(i=0;i<8;i++)\
                                     {str+=\"<tr><td bgcolor=pink>BUTTON #\"+i+\"</td>\";\
                                     if(PORTD&(1<<i)){str+=\"<td bgcolor=red>ON\";}\
                                     else {str+=\"<td bgcolor=#cccccc>OFF\";}\
                                     str+=\"</td></tr>\";}\
                                     document.write(str) ;\
                            </script>\
" ;
```

Note the "\" at the end of each line is due to it being a string in C over multiple lines.

```html
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=http://192.168.0.28\">
<HTML>
      <HEAD>
            <TITLE>Web Server</TITLE>
            <h1>Mini Web Server</h1>
            <script src=/s></script>
                    <table><tr><td valign=top><table border=1 style="font-size:20px ;font-family: terminal ;">
                            <tr><th colspan=2>ADC</th></tr>
                            <tr><td>AN3</td><td><script>document.write(AN3)</script></td></tr>
                     </table>
                            </td><td><table border=1 style="font-size:20px ;font-family: terminal ;">
                            <tr><th colspan=2>PORTD</th></tr>
                            <script>
                                     var str,i;str="";for(i=0;i<8;i++)
                                     {str+="<tr><td bgcolor=pink>BUTTON #"+i+"</td>";
                                     if(PORTD&(1<<i)){str+="<td bgcolor=red>ON";}
                                     else {str+="<td bgcolor=#cccccc>OFF";}
                                     str+="</td></tr>";}
                                     document.write(str) ;
                            </script>
```

Comment: Try providing a real [mcve].

Comment: Its pretty minimal as it is. There is really only 3 items, a heading and 2 tables. If I remove them it will be an empty page. Anyway I incorporated the heading into the heading of another table around it with invisible borders. It looks good and there is no flicker. Am still curious as to why a heading would cause flicker if amyone has experienced that before.

Comment: "Its pretty minimal as it is." — But not really complete (the script is missing) and expecting people to convert the C to HTML in order to test it is unreasonable.

Comment: The script is actually in the response from the server  and looks like the following (var AN3=xyz;var PORTD=xyz;var PORTE=xyz) These values are taken from code on the STM analogue data and io and the code is quite long and complex so adding that would not make it minimal. I left it in C format as it was running on the MCU  which was written in C and most likely debugged in C. However I have converted it and added that version in the edits to.